# Show DropDown in Gridview when specific row checkboox is selected

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I want specific row dropdown to be shown when the same row's checkbox is selected. But having problem as all the dropdowns of the grid are shown on one row's checkbox selection.
This is the Grid:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Advertise Id" HeaderStyle-Width="150px" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="14px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="text-align: left;">
                             <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="120px" ReadOnly="true" ID="TextBoxAdvertiseId" Text='<%# Eval("AdvertiseIdName")%>' />
                                <input type="checkbox" class="CheckBoxImage" onclick="CheckBoxImage()" />

                            <asp:DropDownList CssClass="DDAdvertise" runat="server" Width="130px" ID="drpdwnadvertiseAdd"></asp:DropDownList>

                                 </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the jquery Code:

```
  function CheckBoxImage() {
        var flag = false;
        $('.GridLocation input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {

            var checkbox = $('.GridLocation input[type="checkbox"]');


            var row = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                flag = true;
                $(row).find('.DDAdvertise').show(); // Problem is in .DDAdvertise as it is a classname so it's selecting all the dropdowns

            } else {
                $(row).find('.DDAdvertise').hide();
            }
            if (flag) {
                $(row).find('.DDAdvertise').show();
            }
            else {
                $(row).find('.DDAdvertise').hide();
            }
        });
    }
```

Now, the problem is i am using class name (.DDAdvertise) in jquery which is showing all the dropdowns. I want the specific dropdown to be shown whose row's checkbox is selected.

Comment: Adding the generated html will make it quite easy to give the solution

Comment: What is `var row = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();` I don't believe this will be your specific `tr`

Comment: Yes, it is the specific tr

Comment: This is what i have done

Comment: Show your table in HTML, I still don't believe that `row` is your current `tr`

Comment: try  $(row).closest('.DDAdvertise').show(); or $(row).children('.DDAdvertise').show()

Comment: Instead of `$(row).find('.DDAdvertise')` try `$(this).closest('tr').find('.DDAdvertise')`